# What is the most natural definition of the weak hypercharge coupling constant if grand unification is wrong?

Tags: standard-model, physical-constants, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

A tricky question. Here is the famous graph of the running of the three coupling constants in the standard model:
[image: Running of the gauge couplings]

The graph shows, in its top curve, the running of the coupling constant $\alpha_1$. This is the coupling of the weak hypercharge coupling constant for the weak hypercharge group $\mathrm{U}(1)_{Y}$, which is one of the three gauge groups of the Standard Model of particle physics.

But there is a tricky detail. In that curve, $\alpha_1$ is multiplied with $5/3$. This factor $5/3$ comes from the assumption that GUTs are valid. The factor ensures that the various group traces of $\mathrm{U}(1)_Y$, $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ are normalized in the correct way when they form the $\mathrm{SU}(5)$, $\mathrm{SO}(10)$ or any other grand unification gauge group.

In the case that grand unification is wrong, the factor $5/3$ cannot be deduced. Which factor would be natural in this case?

Clarification added, after remarks by Lubos Motl: it is assumed in the question that the usual definition of the weak hypercharge is used, $Y_W = 2 (Q - T_3)$, in which left-handed quarks have hypercharge $1/3$.

Answer (score 3):

There is of course no unique answer because if the normal GUT embedding and theory is wrong, there may still be another valid theory that naturally involves the same or (almost) any other rescaling of the hypercharge fine-structure constant.

If you say that GUT is *wrong*, it is far from specifying what is actually *right*. When it comes to coupling constants and other things, GUT is more predictive than theories without any unification - that's a characteristic feature of unifying theories. So if you say that GUT is *wrong*, you just reduce the ability to predict and explain patterns in Nature, so you can't expect that by this negative assumption, you will obtain positive predictions. One shouldn't expect that by throwing out theories that are meant to explain something, one automatically finds different answers to the questions.

Of course, if you assume a normalization with no relationship between any groups where the hypercharge $U(1)$ is normalized just like any other $U(1)$ would be, and your goal is to make the formulae as simple as possible on the paper (which is not really a physical criterion), then $5/3$ is replaced by $1$. You just omit the $5/3$ factor. But this is a kind of vacuous statement because one may only compare the fine-structure constants of the different group factors if there is *some* relationship between them which is either grand unification or plays the same role.

One more preemptive comment: at low energies, it is not true that the hypercharge fine-structure constant renormalized by another simple factor such as $5/3$ yields the electromagnetic fine-structure constant. At the GUT scale, similar relations exist but the electromagnetic fine-structure constant is not well-defined there.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. You can see that I do not speak about the fine structure constant at all in this question, but only, as you kindly explained to me, about the hypercharge coupling constant.

Comment: The issue I have is that I am not sure at all that 1 is more natural than 5/3; it could equally be another value. In fact, a value of 1 would mean that U(1) and SU(2) have equal coupling constants, and that the weak mixing angle has sin^2 = 1/2. It is not obvious that this is the most natural choice.

Comment: I was only thinking what happens if GUT is wrong. Taking your remark to the extreme, it would mean that normalization of the weak hypercharge is not fixed at all if GUTs are wrong.

Comment: But the normalization must be fixed somehow, because the normalization fixes/enters the weak mixing angle.

Comment: After all, coupling constants can be measured, so it must be possible to define them uniquely.

Comment: Maybe the question would have to be rephrased in a way that shows a graph with a quantity that is normalization independent. There is a freedom in defining any coupling constant; the full coupling is given by the product of the quantum number and the coupling constant. There is a freedom to shuffle factors between the two. An ideal graph would show the product of the two, so that shuffling issues are eliminated.

Comment: Simply said, I disagree that a GUT or something similar is needed to compare the three constants. This is not correct. The idea of the question is to assume that the standard model is correct at all energies and then draw the graph of the couplings, in an normalization-independent way.

Comment: @Claude: "Taking your remark to the extreme, it would mean that normalization of the weak hypercharge is not fixed at all if GUTs are wrong." - There is nothing extreme about this statement. It is totally harmless, innocent, obviously true, and it was the main point that my answer wanted to convey, indeed. You may normalize your fields in any way you want, and if there's no unification-like link between different fields, you may naturally normalize different fields differently, too.

Comment: @Claude: "After all, coupling constants can be measured, so it must be possible to define them uniquely." - Coupling constants may be measured e.g. from the scattering of charged particles with unit charges. But for $U(1)$ gauge groups underlying charges, the "unit" charges are notoriously ambiguous. Even for the electric charge, it's really questionable whether the unit charge is carried by the positron, $+e$, or the down-antiquark, $+e/3$. In more complicated theories with more general spectrum, it becomes even more questionable what is the "unit charge", and therefore "what is $g$", too.

Comment: In the particular case of hypercharge, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercharge to get some idea about the values. Quarks and leptons have $Y$ equal to various multiples of $1/3$. Moreover, there exist two comparably frequent conventions on whether $Q=I_3+Y$ or $I_3+Y/2$, adding another ambiguity of a factor of two into the conventions on the normalization of $Y$; in the non-$1/2$ convention, $Y$ is a multiple of $1/6$. What can be measured is e.g. the scattering amplitude of two down-quarks but the coupling constant is just one factor in one term in the total expression.